# Remove bottom line on DateTimePicker

Tags: datetimepicker

HelloEverybody,

I hope that you are doing well.
I am trying to remove bottom line on datetimepicker in Flutter but I do not find the solution. Some help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks.[image: I have attached a screenshot of the UI.]

```
Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.0, 2.0, 15.0, 1.0),
                        child: DateTimePicker(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                          ),
                          type: DateTimePickerType.dateTimeSeparate,
                          dateMask: 'd MMM yyyy',
                          controller: _controlerTaskDueDate,
//initialValue: DateTime.now().toString(),
                          firstDate: DateTime(2020),
                          lastDate: DateTime(2200),
                          icon: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.event),
                          ),
                          dateLabelText: 'Due Date',
                          timeLabelText: "Due Time",

//use24HourFormat: false,
                          selectableDayPredicate: (date2) {
                            if (date2.weekday == 6 || date2.weekday == 7) {
                              return true;
                            }
                            return true;
                          },
                          onChanged: (valDueDate) => setState(() => _valueTaskDueDateChanged = valDueDate),
                          validator: (valDueDate) {
                            setState(() => _valueTaskDueDateToValidate = valDueDate);
                            return null;
                          },
                          onSaved: (valDueDate) => setState(() => _valueTaskDueDateSaved = valDueDate),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your `DateTimePicker()` widget, add this decoration:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
  border: InputBorder.none,
),
```

**UPDATE:**

Since my previous answer was overriding the DateTimePicker decorations, I found this to work:

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      border: InputBorder.none,
    )
  ),
  child: //your card widget,
),
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried. The date time picker desappear. I should have mentioned that the datetimepicker is on a form. May be this is why. Please, can you advise? Many thanks

Comment: Would you be able to share what your code looks like?

Comment: Yes. Here it is.

Comment: Yeah I'm having trouble figuring this one out! Seems like using the decoration property overrides everything. I'll keep trying